# SQL JSON_VALUE returning NULLs

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2019

I have a JSON string in a column (Result) that is like this:

```
{"DisplayCommandList":[{"address":"10 Test Avenue","dwelling":true"}]}
```

How do I extract the address part i.e. 10 Test Avenue

I have tried:

```
SELECT
JSON_VALUE([Result], '$.DisplayCommandList.address'),
JSON_VALUE([Result], '$.DisplayCommandList.address[0]'),
JSON_VALUE([Result], '$.DisplayCommandList.address[1]'),
JSON_VALUE([Result], '$.DisplayCommandList.address[2]'),
JSON_VALUE([Result], '$.DisplayCommandList[0].address')
FROM Table;
```

But they all return NULL - what am I missing?

Comment: `$.DisplayCommandList[0].address`.

Comment: I'd, personally, suggest `OPENJSON` instead. (Though the JSON you've given us isn't valid, due to the trailing double quote after `true`).

Comment: @JeroenMostert still returning NULLs

Comment: For a whole object you need `JSON_QUERY`

Comment: [Then `Table` doesn't contain what you expect](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=fefbb41c7eee6d0321238a8d1fb75140).

Comment: @JeroenMostert strange - I genuinely receive null when performed via SSMS

Comment: Interestingly, your JSON is actually invalid (that `"` after `true` isn't supposed to be there) but the JSON parser apparently doesn't care, though `ISJSON` dutifully returns `0`.

Comment: mmmm I'm receiving from a website, unmodified

Comment: @JeroenMostert when you parse it with `OPENJSON` [it does care](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2a9c44afcff57a663c10d5c30919766a), which is even more odd.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=05a2a34af27d63b88fd63929c47e68f6

Comment: @Larnu: things fail once more once one selects `dwelling` instead of `address`, suggesting `JSON_VALUE` is implemented through a different, incremental parser. Indeed, it will happily parse `'{"DisplayCommandList":[{"address":"10 Test Avenue"'`, which has just enough to satisfy our path expression.

Comment: its importing via a Python web scraping script, so I'll see if that is somehow modifying it.  Thanks for all your help though, I really appreciate it

Comment: Indeed, this is "somewhat documented" by omission: "If `JSON_VALUE` finds JSON that is not valid in expression before it finds the value identified by path, the function returns an error. If `JSON_VALUE` doesn't find the value identified by path, it scans the entire text and returns an error if it finds JSON that is not valid anywhere in expression". Note that it does *not* say that *no* error will be produced if the value is found, this is just heavily implied. Whether this is just obtuse wording, or they're leaving room to start returning errors in the future, is the reader's guess.